# sqlAppendTable and dbExecute work, but not dbAppendTable. why?

Tags: r, postgresql, r-dbi

I have a data.frame that I am trying to append to a table in a PostgreSQL database in `R` using the `DBI` package.

```
library(DBI)
library(RPostgreSQL)

mydrv  <-  dbDriver(drvName = "PostgreSQL")
mydbcon  <-  dbConnect(drv = mydrv , host = myhostname , dbname = mydbname , username = myusername , password = mypassword  )
```

If I try to do `dbAppendTable`, it fails with a strange error message:

```
dbAppendTable( conn = mydbcon , name = mytable , value = mydata )
```

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :    RS-DBI
>   driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or
>   near "," LINE 4:   (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

But if I do it in two steps with `sqlAppendTable` and `dbExecute`, then it works fine:

```
append_cmd  <-  sqlAppendTable( con = mydbcon , table = mytable , values = mydata , row.names = FALSE )
dbExecute( conn = mydbcon , statement = append_cmd )
```

The documentation for `dbAppendTable` says:

> The dbAppendTable() method assumes that the table has been created
>   beforehand, e.g. with dbCreateTable(). The default implementation
>   calls sqlAppendTableTemplate() and then dbExecute() with the param
>   argument. Backends compliant to ANSI SQL 99 which use ? as a
>   placeholder for prepard queries don't need to override it. Backends
>   with a different SQL syntax which use ? as a placeholder for prepared
>   queries can override sqlAppendTable(). Other backends (with different
>   placeholders or with entirely different ways to create tables) need to
>   override the dbAppendTable() method.

The part about `'?'` being the placeholder seems relevant, but I don't understand how it fits in. Why does PostgreSQL not satisfy this?  Why do I have to do it in two steps to get it to work?

Comment: Does this work with the RPostgres package?

Comment: Yes, `dbAppendTable` does seem to work with a connection created using the RPostgres package.

Comment: Also note that `dbAppendTable` and `dbExecute` fail with either RPostgres or RPostgreSQL connections if you try to set the table name using a schema qualifier, e.g., `table = c('schema_name','table_name')` or `table = 'schema_name.table_name'`, however, the following does appear to work: `dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = c('schema_name','table_name'), value = mytable, overwrite = F, append = T, row.names = F)`.